# react-admin: what is authParams for?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am using [react-admin](https://marmelab.com/react-admin) and I am looking at the [documentation page](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authorization.html#restricting-access-to-content-in-custom-pages-or-menus) for creating page with permissions

The example shows:

```
const MyPageWithPermissions = ({ location, match }) => (
    <WithPermissions
        authParams={{ key: match.path, params: route.params }}
        // location is not required but it will trigger a new permissions check if specified when it changes
        location={location}
        render={({ permissions }) => <MyPage permissions={permissions} /> }
    />
);

export default MyPageWithPermissions;
```

First of all:

- `route` is not defined, what is the real value?

I would like to know:

- What is `authParams` used for? Is it required or optional?
- Could `authParams` be skipped?
- If it's required, why is it not set automatically directly in `WithPermissions` Component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are for custom params you'd like to check in your `authProvider`. They will be passed to it when `WithPermissions` calls it.

They are optional though as you can see in the next example for a [custom menu](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authorization.html#restricting-access-to-content-in-custom-menu)

Comment: This may allow you to check for feature flags for example

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am looking at https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-core/src/auth/WithPermissions.tsx#L68. Does `props.render` and `props.children` does the same, which example is good between the documentation and that one?

Comment: The one from documentation. You can use `children` but it will only accept a function, just like render. I would love a PR fixing the comment :)

Comment: Just did it here https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/3053, I am still not sure about what is `route.params` in the example here?.

Comment: Should probably be `match.params`